# How to fade in image when in view with CSS

Tags: css, animation, fade

Is there a way to fade in an image when a user scrolls the image into view using purely if not mostly CSS?

I have a bunch of images displayed and I'd like the images to appear as they scroll down as a nice effect.

Comment: If you decide to use jQuery ever, try this: http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/

Answer (score 1):

If you want the image to fade in only when the user can see it (after scrolling the page), you can't do it with CSS only. To make the fade in/fade out effect on hover use `opacity` and `transition`. **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/CA5Qr/)**

```
img{
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: all 1s;
}
img:hover{
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

If you want to use JQuery, it's possible. See **[this exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/CA5Qr/4/)**.

Comment: @Anthony does this answer your question?

Comment: OP specifically asking to fade in an element when scrolled into the view, not when hovered.

Answer (score -2):

```
img
{
opacity:0.4;
}
img:hover
{
opacity:1.0;
}
```

The CSS3 property for transparency is opacity.The opacity property can take a value from 0.0 - 1.0\
    A lower value makes the element more transparent.

```
img:hover {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Check this link, it would be of great help for you:-
    http://designshack.net/?p=36895

Comment: Wrong answer, hover doesn't apply here. OP specifically asking about fading an element when it gets scrolled into view.